# is it possible to use iframe in phonegap ios application

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe, inappbrowser

I've tried a lot of code samples and methods but nothing works.. iframes in phonegap application doesn't load url in src attribute.
I want to learn is it possible to use iframe in a phonegap iOS application. And is there a way to show a website inside my app (except InAppBrowser). InAppBrowser just backgrounds my app and open safari. I want to show a url inside my own interface.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have iFrames in your app to show some web pages but you have to be careful about which website you want to load in iFrame because most of the popular websites (FB, Twitter etc) doesn't allow their website to be rendered in iFrame using META tags like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny" />
```